# Programmatically show the popup from a DatePicker

Tags: windows-phone-7, silverlight-toolkit, windows-phone-7.1

I'm using the DatePicker from the Silverlight Toolkit on Mango

I want to programmatically display the date picker full mode display, but I can't see any API hook to do that at the moment.

Is this possible? or do I have to implement this myself by (intelligently) writing a new control?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sadly Matt was right - there's no public or protected API to hack into and security prevents the use of Reflection - so I've +1'd his answer... and a full answer is:

- take the files from Silverlight.codeplex.com
- either use the whole project or create your own library with just DatePicker.cs, DateTimePickerBase.cs and the DatePicker Style template from Generic.xaml
- in your DateTimePickerBase, add:

  ```
  public event EventHandler<EventArgs> PopupClosedByDateSelection;
  ```
- in ClosePickerPage() inside PopupClosedByDateSelection inside the `if(_dateTimePickerPage.Value.HasValue)` block, add:

  ```
              if (PopupClosedByDateSelection != null)
                  PopupClosedByDateSelection(this, EventArgs.Empty);
  ```

This seems to work for the Back button case as well as for the cancel and OK cases.

Answer (score 1):

Build your own I'm afraid.

Be careful about the user expectations around opening it automatically though. ;)